# Filtering 2nd and 3rd pickerviews based on selection from 1st using structs

Tags: ios, json, swift, struct, uipickerview

I searched(and found some using static arrays) but couldn't find anything related to what I am trying to do with JSON populated structs.

I'm new to Swift and StackExchange so if I missed it please let me know!

I have three structs being populated from JSON code.
Note: departmentName is the same as Department in the other two structs

```
struct Dept: Decodable {
let departmentName: String 
}

struct Company: Decodable {
let companyName: String
let Department: String
}

struct Spread: Decodable {
let spreadName: String
let spreadType: String
let Department: String
}
```

These load on viewDidLoad. 
Example of data in array(ish) form would be:

```
Department = "Department 1"
Company = ["Company 1":"Department 1","Company 2":"Department 2"]
Spread = ["Spread 1":"Department 1","Spread 2 ":"Department 2"]
```

My current code for the PickerView functions:

```
public func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

public func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    var countRows : Int = dep.count
    if pickerView == companyPicker {
        countRows = self.company.count
    }
    else if pickerView == spreadPicker {
        countRows = self.spread.count
    }
    else if pickerView == incidentPicker {
        countRows = self.incident.count
    }
    return countRows
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if pickerView == deptPicker {
        let titleRow = dep[row].departmentName
        return titleRow
    }
    else if pickerView == companyPicker {
        let titleRow = company[row].companyName
        return titleRow
    }
    else if pickerView == spreadPicker {
        let titleRow = spread[row].spreadName
        return titleRow
    }
    else if pickerView == incidentPicker {
        let titleRow = incident[row].incidentTypeName
        return titleRow
    }
    return ""
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if pickerView == deptPicker {
        self.deptartmentTextField.text = self.dep[row].departmentName
        self.deptartmentTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    else if pickerView == companyPicker {
        self.companyTextField.text = self.company[row].companyName
        self.companyTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    else if pickerView == spreadPicker {
        self.spreadTextField.text = self.spread[row].spreadName
        self.spreadTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    else if pickerView == incidentPicker {
        self.incidentTextField.text = self.incident[row].incidentTypeName
        self.incidentTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

I guess my biggest question is if there is a way to filter the Company and Spread pickers based on the Dept picker.

Comment: I solved this on my own. Incase anyone comes looking. I added functions that filter and append to a new array for the second and third pickerviews and then reloaded the data.

Comment: You can answer your own question to make it more clean for interested people.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem I added two functions that filtered the data from the first Department picker. I added these to my didSelectRow picker function. I then reloaded the second and third picker after filtering.